# FATAL: password authentication when bucardo add tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, database-replication, bucardo

**System specification:**

- Ubuntu 14.04
- bucardo version 4.99.10
- psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.14

**What I have tried so far?**

I have created master database with openerp postgres user.

```
- Setup Source Database

    export SOURCE_HOST=localhost
    export SOURCE_PORT=5432  
    export SOURCE_DATABASE=master
    export SOURCE_USERNAME=openerp  
    export SOURCE_PASSWORD=openerp

- Setup Destination Database

    export DEST_HOST=localhost 
    export DEST_PORT=5432  
    export DEST_DATABASE=slave  
    export DEST_USERNAME=openerp  
    export DEST_PASSWORD=openerp    

- Finally, the tables to be migrated

    export TABLES="-t res_partner"

    export TABLES_WITH_SPACES="res_partner"

- Set up the Destination Database

    cat >> $HOME/.pgpass <<EOL  
    $DEST_HOST:$DEST_PORT:$DEST_DATABASE:$DEST_USERNAME:$DEST_PASSWORD
    $SOURCE_HOST:$SOURCE_PORT:$SOURCE_DATABASE:$SOURCE_USERNAME:$SOURCE_PASSWORD
    EOL  

- Create schema.sql 

- Create Slave database

- Load schema into Slave

- Setting up Bucardo Sync (Source Database and  Destination Database) 

- Now I am trying to add the tables we want to migrate and add them to a "copying herd"

    ./bucardo add tables res_partner db=master
```

I got following error:

> openerp@odedra-Lenovo-Z50-70:/usr/local/src/bucardo$ ./bucardo add tables res_partner db=master
>   DBI connect('dbname=master;host=localhost;port=5432','openerp',...) failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "openerp"
>   FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "openerp" at ./bucardo line 8632.

I have analytic script bucardo. I have confusion with dbuser and dbpass variable declared at line number 84, 85.

```
(I have tried with dbuser = 'openerp' and dbpass='openerp' but result same)
```

My *pg_hba.conf*

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                ident

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

List of database:

```
                                   List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 bucardo     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 master      | openerp  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 slave       | openerp  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 slave_copy  | openerp  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 slave_copy1 | openerp  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 slave_copy2 | openerp  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
             |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
             |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

May you guide me what should I change to fix above error or helpful related links?

How can I achieve master-slave functionality using Bucardo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that have problem with *pg_hba.conf* file. To resolve error, I have added below line to that file.

```
local   all             openerp                                ident
```