# Odoo 15: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "odoo15"

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-15

I have installed Odoo 15 and postgreSQL with all other Odoo 15 dependencies.
I am facing a problem when I going to run this by custom.conf file with another port(8015).
Note that, **I didn't have any custom module till now**.
In port: 8069, I create a database and I run it after setting the custom.conf file with related and valid parameters.
But still it say password authentication error.
Can anybody suggest me the solution, please?
I attached all the screenshot related to this problem as I far as I understood.

custom.conf

```
[options]
addons_path = /home/src/odoo/addons,/home/src/odoo/odoo/addons,/home/src/custom,/home/tarikol/Projects/OdooProjects/custom
admin_passwd = Admin123
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo15
db_password = odoo15
http_port = 8015
```

postgresSQL

```
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 mydb      | tarikol  | UTF8     | C           | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 odoo15    | odoo     | UTF8     | C           | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)
```

Odoo 15 page, from where I created the database.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207304/fatal-password-authentication-when-bucardo-add-tables ?

Comment: Are you sure you have a postgres user "odoo15" with password "odoo15"? Your db "odoo15" is owned by user "odoo" not "odoo15".

Comment: Have you tried without admin_passwd in your custom conf file. It was working fine ? Also avoid giving the word 'admin' in master password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error states that the `db_user` and `db_password` that Odoo server using to connect to Postgres is wrong.

You can try to run the command `\du` in Postgres and make sure the odoo15 user is there and has `Superuser, Create role, Create DB` roles.

If you found the odoo15 user then you can change password as below:

```
ALTER USER odoo15 WITH PASSWORD 'odoo15';
```

If you created the db user from ubuntu as below then you can connect to db without password ([Odoo Installation Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/administration/install/install.html#id13)):

```
$ sudo -u postgres createuser -s $USER
```

> Because your PostgreSQL user has the same name as your Unix login, you
> will be able to connect to the database without password.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something else but in the .conf you have the db password set to 0odoo15 and in the picture you have odoo15

Comment: Sorry, but I rewrite it to odoo15 again , but still problem remain as  it is.